# Getting class name of children Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get the class name of the specific div nested in a list item on hover using jquery. When I hover over the list item it currently returns undefined. The class name which I need is the second class name of the particular div so for example `<div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-one"></div>` for this div `navlink-underline` would be the first class and `navlink-underline-one` is the second class. The second class is what I am trying to return.

```js
$('.nav-link').mouseenter(function() {
  console.log($(this).children().attr('class'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-list">
  <li><a class="nav-link navlink-one" href="">Home</a><div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-one"></div></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link navlink-two" href="">About Us</a><div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-two"></div></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link navlink-three" href="">Products</a><div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-three"></div></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link navlink-four" href="">References</a><div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-four"></div></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link navlink-five" href="">Contact</a><div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-five"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the selection of the `navlink-underline` element. You tried to select it with the `children()` method, but that only works if the element you're seeking is a child. In your case it was het *next sibling*. The `next()` method will help you get that element.

From there you'll need to access the `classList` property of the element you're seeking and use the `item` method on that property to select the 2nd class in its list.

```js
$('.nav-link').on('mouseenter', function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  const $underline = $this.next();
  const secondClass = $underline.get(0).classList.item(1);
  console.log(secondClass);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-list">
  <li><a class="nav-link navlink-one" href="">Home</a><div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-one"></div></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link navlink-two" href="">About Us</a><div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-two"></div></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link navlink-three" href="">Products</a><div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-three"></div></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link navlink-four" href="">References</a><div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-four"></div></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link navlink-five" href="">Contact</a><div class="navlink-underline navlink-underline-five"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion

```
$('.nav-link').mouseenter(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/)[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

```js
$('li').mouseenter(function() {
  console.log($(this).children("div").attr('class').split(/\s+/)[1]);
});
```